# How to configure Extent report for temyers/Cucumber-JVM-Parallel plugin

Tags: extentreports, selenium-extent-report

How to configure Extent report for temyers/Cucumber-JVM-Parallel plugin?

We are using Teamyers Cucumber-JVM-Parallel-plugin to run Selenium cucumber tests in parallel using Maven-surefire-plugin.
Using Cucumber-JVM-Parallel-plugin, we bypass need of traditional Cucumber-runner class & its multiple instances are being generated on run-time by this plugin

For each parallel run, it generates separate cucumber-report.

[image]

```
 <plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.temyers</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-parallel-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.0</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generateRunners</id>
      <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>generateRunners</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <!-- Mandatory -->
        <!-- List of package names to scan for glue code. -->
        <glue>
          <package>com.example</package>
          <package>com.example.other</package>
        </glue>
        <!-- These are optional, with the default values -->
        <!-- Where to output the generated tests -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources/cucumber</outputDirectory>
        <!-- The directory, which must be in the root of the runtime classpath, containing your feature files.  -->
        <featuresDirectory>src/test/resources/features/</featuresDirectory>
        <!-- Directory where the cucumber report files shall be written  -->
        <cucumberOutputDir>target/cucumber-parallel</cucumberOutputDir>
        <!-- List of cucumber plugins. When none are provided the json formatter is used. For more 
             advanced usage see section about configuring cucumber plugins -->
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
              <name>json</name>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
              <name>com.example.CustomHtmlFormatter</name>
              <extension>html</extension>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!-- CucumberOptions.strict property -->
        <strict>true</strict>
        <!-- CucumberOptions.monochrome property -->
        <monochrome>true</monochrome>
        <!-- The tags to run, maps to CucumberOptions.tags property. Default is no tags. -->
        <tags>
          <tag>@billing</tag>
          <tag>~@billing</tag>
          <tag>@important</tag>
          <tag>@important,@billing</tag>
        </tags>
        <!-- Generate TestNG runners instead of JUnit ones. --> 
        <useTestNG>false</useTestNG>
        <!-- The naming scheme to use for the generated test classes.  One of ['simple', 'feature-title', 'pattern'] -->
        <namingScheme>simple</namingScheme>
        <!-- The class naming pattern to use.  Only required/used if naming scheme is 'pattern'.-->
        <namingPattern>Parallel{c}IT</namingPattern>
        <!-- One of [SCENARIO, FEATURE]. SCENARIO generates one runner per scenario.  FEATURE generates a runner per feature. -->
        <parallelScheme>SCENARIO</parallelScheme>
        <!-- Specify a custom template for the generated sources (this is a path relative to the project base directory) -->
        <customVmTemplate>src/test/resources/cucumber-custom-runner.vm</customVmTemplate>
        <!-- Specify a custom package name for generated sources. Default is no package.-->
        <packageName>com.example</packageName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

How to configure Extent report for it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Since version 4.0.0 cucumber supports parallel execution](https://cucumber.io/blog/2018/09/24/announcing-cucumber-jvm-4-0-0). You can use that and use Extent as you would for a normal execution.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Is Cucumber-jvm-parallel plugin still supported? Or how to generate multiple parallel runners on without using it?

Comment: You don't have to generate multiple runners anymore. Cucumber JVM can execute scenarios/features in parallel with a single runner. Check the linked documentation/announcement to see what is applicable to your situation.

Comment: Could you advise me how to achieve parallel execution using Gradle variant of Cucumber-JVM? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/master/junit-platform-engine